# web3j - Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Tags: web3j

I am trying to create java wrappers for smart contracts, but my web3j installation is not working correctly. If I try to create a new web3j project using `web3j new` I get following error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
> Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache [in thread "Daemon worker"]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 778ms
```

I am using windows and my current Java version is:

```
java version "18.0.2.1" 2022-08-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2.1+1-1, mixed mode, sharing)
```